# How to create a multiple page pdf with pytesseract?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

I'm trying to mark only a few words in a pdf and with the results I want to make a new pdf using only pytesseract.

Here is the code:

```
images = convert_from_path(name,poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-0.68.0\bin')

    for i in images:
        img = cv.cvtColor(np.array(i),cv.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img,output_type=Output.DICT,lang='eng+equ',config="--psm 6")
        boxes = len(d['level'])
        for i in range(boxes):
            for e in functionEvent: #functionEvent is a list of strings
                if e in d['text'][i]:
                    (x,y,w,h) = (d['left'][i],d['top'][i],d['width'][i],d['height'][i])
                    cv.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
   
        pdf = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(img,extension='pdf')
        with open('results.pdf','w+b') as f:
            f.write(pdf)
```

What have I tried:

```
with open('results.pdf','a+b') as f:
                f.write(pdf)
```

If you know how can I fix this just let me know.
Also I don't care at all if you recommand another module or your opinion how am I supposed to write code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try using PyPDF2 to link your pdfs together.
Firstly you extract your text from pdf with tesseract OCR and store it into list object like this :

```
for filename in tqdm(os.listdir(in_dir)):

  img = Image.open(os.path.join(in_dir,filename))

  pdf = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(img, lang='slk', extension='pdf')
  pdf_pages.append(pdf)
```

then iterate trough each processed image or file, read the bytes and add pages using PdfFileReader like this(do not forget to import io):

```
pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

for page in pdf_pages:
  pdf = PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(page))
  pdf_writer.addPage(pdf.getPage(0))
```

In the end create the file and store data to it:

```
file = open(out_dir, "w+b")
pdf_writer.write(file)
file.close()
```